# R - Apply function to regex match

Tags: r, regex, gsub

Let's say I have a string like so:

```
txt <- "This is an example of a Tweet with a #HashTag."
```

I want to find every hashtag via regex. Not only do I want to replace the "#" with the marker `<hashtag>`. I also want to apply a function to further preprocess the content of every hashtag (everything after the "#" in the hashtag), like so:

```
  pp_hashtag = function(hashtag) {
    ifelse(
      grepl("^[[:upper:]]+$", hashtag),
      paste(hashtag, "<allcaps>"),
      gsub("(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])", " ", hashtag, perl = T)
    )
  }
```

The above function breaks the hashtag into constituent words if possible, or if not because it contains all capital letters, marks it as so.

How can I do this? If there's a better way to do this I'm open to that as well.

Comment: What do you expect as the result? .can you show your expected output?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
tweet_preprocessor = function(tweets_txt) {
  pp_hashtag = function(hashtag) {
    hashtag = substring(hashtag, 2)
    paste("<hashtag>", ifelse(
      grepl("^[[:upper:]]+$", hashtag),
      paste(hashtag, "<allcaps>"),
      gsub("(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])", " ", hashtag, perl = T)
    ))
  }
  gr = gregexpr("#\\w+", tweets_txt, perl = T)
  mat = regmatches(tweets_txt, gr)
  regmatches(tweets_txt, gr) = lapply(mat, pp_hashtag)
  tweets_txt
}
```

Got it. Just got to use `gregexpr` and `regmatches`.

Comment: Your code returns `"This is an example of a Tweet with a <hashtag> Hash Tag."` - is it the expected output? I have tried a  different solution, and got `"This is an example of a Tweet with a <hashtag>Hash Tag."`. Could you please clarify if you need to replace `#` with `<hashtag>` and then insert a space before each captital letter but the first one?